# Which items to verify in SAMLResponse for single sigin on(SSO)?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I"m going to make SSO function by SAML2.0.
And I'm searching what item to be verified in response & assertion of SAMLResponse.
But there is no clear answer and suggestion.

I just read 4.1.4.3  Message Processing Rules, but not sure which items they are.
https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Signature? No. And then audience restriction, validity etc.

Comment: If you are a beginner here, it would be much safer to rely on an external component that does it for you. Otherwise you risk misimplementing some details that would leave your site vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SAML Response with Signed Assertion` [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php) to see what's in a typical one.

If you want someone to login to your app using `SAML`, your app first has to satisfy itself that the user is who they claim to be. It does that by verifying the `SignedInfo` on the `Response`. It uses the public key of the IdP to do that. Your app is the SP and should know how to find the public key of the Idp, from its `SAML` metadata. You can use the `Issuer` to get the IdP's `entityID`. Then, in `AudienceRestriction`, make sure the `Response` is intended for your app.

Once the basic verification passes, you can use the `AttributeStatement` to create an account for the user. The `Attribute`s you need for that are in there.

So it's essentially a two part process. In the first part, you make sure the `Response` is valid, comes from the expected IdP and is intended for your app.

The second part is using the `Attribute`s to manage an account for the user in your app.

There are various refinements such as `NotBefore` and `NotOnOrAfter` for `Attribute` values but those are the basic steps.